# Is it possible to find the flux of a vector field through a surface (e.g. disk, ellipsoid) without computing an integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces, stokes-theorem

My multi-variable calculus professor posed this during class, and I can't figure out how this would be possible.  Would you need the equations of the surface?  I'd expect that the value of the vector field would be necessary, is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "computing an integral". You can certainly calculate those things via geometry (under certain special circumstances, obviously).

Comment: @Jared are there certain cases in which the flux can be easily assumed?  Maybe if the surface or vector field has some trait, then the flux is zero?

Comment: @Jared is that the gradient of the cross product of the gradient of F with F?

Comment: It's (was) the curl (which sort of is the cross product of the gradient operator and $\vec{F}$)...but that's incorrect--I believe what you actually need is the divergence is zero: $\vec{\nabla}\circ\vec{F}$. This is a direct result from Stokes' Theorem (sometimes called Gauss's Theorem).